# How to use " if " condition for multiple checkbox in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, webforms

I used 30 checkboxes in a table, 5 rows and 6 columns. 5 checkboxes are in each row.

I need to satisfy two conditions within this table.

1. The first condition is when three Checkboxes are selected continuously it should display ("You can't select continuous hours").
2. Next condition is, it shouldn't select more than three checkbox in each row.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using asp.net mvc or webforms?  You can accomplish what you need in Javascript

Comment: Show the code please.